# Visual Basic 2008 Combobox item history track (winforms)

Tags: vb.net, winforms, combobox, increment

Is there any method which lets you know the previous selection before last selection in a combobox?

For example let's say a combobox have 3 items : 1,2,3
When selecting item 2 and then 3 (from the dropdown combobox list) I want to know that the previous item after selecting item 3 was the item 2.

Can somebody help me please? I will use this in order to decrease/increase quantities in a Shopping Basket. When the user selects a product the quantity automatically must decrease but if the user changes to another product the quantity of the previous one must be increased again in order to avoid consistency issues.

Comment: I am using windows forms. I tried to explain the problem clearly, i hope you understood :)

Comment: Strange technology to be using a Shopping Basket but there you go...

Comment: It supposed to be an application for a company that sells things to people

Comment: Saving the value in a temporary variable and checking against it every time the selectedItem changes? Just a thought...

Comment: I was thinking about it but i hesitated to try it because I have multiple comboboxes with items so I will need to build a lot of checking validations :(  I will implement this as my last choice. Thanks anyways

Comment: You just need one sub and one array of items or some other collection. Alternatively you can instantiate a class with a number of properties associated to the comboboxes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might help, I'm using a stack so you can see the last added entry. EDIT: On the init, I set an index tag to the combo boxes so you can add to the stack for that combo box in the array. EDIT EDIT: I have added so it searches the form for all the combo box controls and adds them, so you don't have to add the tags or combo boxes manually yourself.

```
 Dim lastSelectedArr() As Stack(Of String)

Public Sub New()

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
    Dim index As Integer = 1

    Dim combos As New List(Of ComboBox)

    For Each c As Control In Me.Controls
        If (c.GetType() = GetType(ComboBox)) Then
            Dim combo As ComboBox = CType(c, ComboBox)
            combo.Tag = index
            combos.Add(CType(c, ComboBox))
            index += 1
        End If
    Next


    ReDim lastSelectedArr(combos.Count - 1)


    For i As Integer = 0 To lastSelectedArr.Length - 1
        lastSelectedArr(i) = New Stack(Of String)
    Next



End Sub


Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged, ComboBox2.SelectedIndexChanged

    Dim cb As ComboBox = CType(sender, ComboBox)


    Dim CBID As Integer = CInt(cb.Tag) - 1

    lastSelectedArr(CBID).Push(cb.SelectedItem)



    Dim retStr As String = String.Empty

    For Each value As String In lastSelectedArr(CBID)
        retStr = retStr + value + ","
    Next

    MessageBox.Show(retStr)
End Sub
```

Comment: any idea how i can apply this method to multiple comboboxes? I will need to initialize more Stacks ?

Comment: @antreasg3 I have updated the code, hopefully that makes sense. This is just one way of doing it